# How to identify a cyclical subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I've been given a piece of homework and it asks which of the two subgroups are cyclic:

a) $⟨1,2,3⟩, id, ⟨1,3,2⟩$ on S<sub>11</sub>

b) $⟨1,2⟩, ⟨3,4⟩, id, ⟨1,2⟩⟨3,4⟩$ on S<sub>5</sub>

Apparently a) is cyclic and b) is not but how do I work this out?

I'm not particularly familiar with notation for groups but in the long-term, it would be useful to understand how to identify future cyclical subgroups.

Ultimately, I will be writing a code to determine whether an input is a cyclical subgroup or not so I'm really look for a somewhat formulaic way to determine this.

Comment: Do you mean $$\langle (123),e,(132) \rangle$$ in $S_{11}$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad notation

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Surely they mean $\{(123),e,(132)\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a) is isomorphic to $$\Bbb Z_3\cong\langle x\mid x^3\rangle,$$ so is cyclic with either nonidentity element as a generator (mapping to $x$), whereas b) is isomorphic to the Klein four group $$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\cong\langle a, b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle$$ under the map given by $(12)\mapsto a, (34)\mapsto b,$ so is thus not cyclic.

The notation I'm using here is that of [presentations of groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

One general method to decide whether a given group is cyclic is to take a nonidentity element then multiply it by itself repeatedly. If you reach every element of the group, then it is cyclic; if not, try another element; and if the group is finite, this process will halt.

Comment: Are you able to make this more generalisable? I'm not really familiar with this notation or what it means to be a cyclic subgroup

Comment: Is that better, @woddal?